# ¿cómo resolver el problema de "Reading from the stream has failed"?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, .net, server

qué tal comunidad, estoy creando una aplicación en .NET que se conecta a una base de datos alojada en un dominio web, hasta no hace mucho la aplicación funcionana sin ningún problema, sin embargo de un día para otro el sistema comenzó arrojar el mensaje de error "Reading from the stream has failed", me doy cuenta que la conexión a la base de datos se cierra mientras el sistema no está en uso, es decir, al abrir la aplicación por primera vez manda este mensaje de error, cierro la aplicación y al volver a ejecutarla se conecta sin problema, pero si dejo de usar la aplicación por 1 o 2 min me vuelve a mandar este mensaje y tengo que volver a iniciarla, repito, esto no pasaba antes, anteriormente se conectaba sin problema pero ahora me ocurre esto, ojalá puedan ayudarme a encontrar una solución. Desde ya Gracias !

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Tengo una cadena de conexión de este tipo: 

 Dim oConexion As New MySqlConnection
        oConexion.ConnectionString = "server=myServerAddress;" &
        "user id=myUser" &
       "password=pass;" &
      "database=myDataBase;" &
      "Allow Zero Datetime=True;" &
      "Convert Zero Datetime=True;"

Pero al ejecutar mi aplicación me arroja el mensaje "Reading from the stream has failed", el sistema ya trabajaba correctamente, llevaba ya algunos meses trabajando sin problemas hasta no hace mucho comenzó con este error y no sé porqué razón ocurrió ni tampoco he podido resolverlo.